# Javascript: function declaration and function expression

Tags: javascript

I don't understand the following Javascript example given by the book "Head First Javascript Programing 2014" on page 469. Can anyone please explain it to me (newbie)? Thank you for your help.

```
function fun(echo) { 
    console.log(echo);
};

fun("hello1");
```

console log prints > hello1

No problem with this.

```
function boo(aFunction) {
    aFunction("boo2");
}
```

Q1: I don't understand this part at all. I can declare "(aFunction)" as an argument of function "boo" without 1st declaring what "aFunction" does?

How does the function "aFunction("boo2");" works? I'm passing a string call "boo2" into the aFunction? But don't I need to declare what aFunction does 1st before passing it a string?

```
boo(fun);
```

console log prints > boo2

Q2: why does it print "boo2"? My confusion stems from the previous question. Maybe if that is answered, I can understand this part?

```
console.log(fun);
```

console log prints > function fun(echo) {console.log(echo);}

I think this is just printing out the type of Function "fun", so this is ok.

```
fun(boo);
```

console log prints > function boo(aFunction) {aFunction("boo");}

Q3: Why does it print out the type for Function "boo?"

```
var moreFun = fun;

moreFun("hello again3");
```

console log prints > hello again3

I read it as var morefun points to/ references fun. So it "becomes" fun. So this is ok.

```
function echoMaker() {
    return fun;
}

var bigFun = echoMaker();
bigFun("Is there an echo4?");
```

console log prints > Is there an echo4?

Q4: Why does it print out the string "Is there an echo4?" What does the "return fun;" do? I did not pass the string "Is there an echo4?" to Function "fun", so how can it print out the string here?

Comment: Read about higher-order functions.

Comment: About Q1: function is an `Object` in JavaScript, with `.call` and `.apply` in its prototype chain, and a special `()` operator predefined. Since it's just an object, it can be passed and returned like other object.

Comment: It's the same with any other function: The parameter name is simply a placeholder for whatever value you will pass in when you call the function. In this case, the argument is expected to be a function. If you pass anything else than a function, you will get an error. Similarly, if you have a function such as `function appendFoo(str) { return str + ' foo'; }`, you expect the value passed to the function to be string. The string doesn't have to exist yet. And if you pass a value of a different data type, you might not get a meaningful result.

Comment: it's much easier to address your concerns and assist if you limit to one question per post.  Also, it doesn't really seem you have an actual issue here; this is much more a discussion which are not encouraged due to the format of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Part:

Functions can be passed in other functions as parameters (Beauty of Javascript) So in your case:

```
function boo(aFunction) {
    aFunction("boo2");
}
```

you passing function body in function boo and since the function you bind at runtime is

```
function fun(echo) { 
    console.log(echo);
};
```

It accepts one parameter and hence does the echo. So in javascript it does a late binding (not compile time) hence it will never error out. Even if you pass multiple arguments even it will take the first one and print that in the console. I think this answers your second question as well.

Your last question:

```
function echoMaker() {
    return fun;
}
```

Over here you returning a function. So in this statement

```
var bigFun = echoMaker();
```

you executed the echoMaker() which will now result in

```
bigFun = fun;
```

Hence when you do

```
bigFun("Is there an echo4?");
```

It will do

```
fun("Is there an echo4");
```

which will then do the console.log

Comment: V31, thank you so much for your detailed explanation :) I'm so sorry for not being able to Vote Up as I do not have a reputable of > 15.